# Multiplying mesh multiple times in Blender

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to create a mesh in the shape of acoustic foam. This foam is used to cancel out echoes and is also used in transportation:

[image]

To create such a material, I add a cube, then I select the upper 4 vertices and click Alt + m, then "At center".

This creates a pyramid.

How could I now multiply this pyramid in order to form such a foam object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a "matrix" of objects, just use the Array modifier twice with the Relative Offset set to x=0 y=1 z=0 and x=1 y=0 z=0 as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add an array modifier to the object

Comment: Great, thank you. This modifier adds copies to the right. Is there a way to have it do to both the right and to the bottom?

Comment: I found a solution: Add an array multiplier, then add like 10 and click "Apply". Now select the entire thing and rotate it and click "Apply rotation". Now add an array modifier again and do the same. Now it has multiplied to all directions. :-)

Comment: @tmighty You don't need to Apply or Rotate - just add two array modifiers, one with the offset in the X direction (the default) and the second in the Y direction (just change the 1.0 for Relative X to 0.0 and the 0.0 for Relative Y to 1.0 on the second modifier).